# Auto increment a variable in regex

Tags: regex, variables, auto-increment

I am using a `Unix.sh` file and in the file I have a regex which has a variable, that has to be incremented every time.The count is set to 1. Every-time it should increment.
stringA=`echo $stringA | sed "s/[A-Za-z]\{3\},[0-9]*/$count++,&,/g"`

So my output should be something like

`prgm([(1,ABC,1,),(2,XYZ,1,),(3,PQR,1,)]),....`

but what I get is

`prgm([(0++,ABC,1,),(0++,XYZ,1,),(0++,PQR,1,)]),....`

Comment: What language/editor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with sed. Go use something modern:

```
perl -pe 's/[A-Z]{3},\d*/$count++.",$&,"/egi'
```

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions are for matching strings. They are not for manipulating variables as the matching occurs.

You don't say what language you are using, but I would suggest you find the way to return all the matches within the given string. Once you have that, you can iterate over the list and insert your value for the incrementing count.